# Is 'user' a valid scheme for HTTP Authorization header?

Tags: http, rest

An [old W3C doc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html) lists 'user' as a valid scheme for the Authorization header and is defined like ...

```
Authorization:  user  fred:mypassword
```

There doesn't seem to be a reference to this in the later RFC2617. Has this been deprecated?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes.

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) makes a number of references to HTTP access authentication by referring to [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) (e.g. [§11 Access Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-11)). Only 2 schemes are discussed in both RFCs (Basic and Digest).

A few more schemes are discussed in [this post](http://blog.distributedmatter.net/post/2008/06/09/HTTP-authentication-mechanisms-and-how-they-could-work-in-Restlet), but the scheme from the W3C site doesn't seem to have been implemented anywhere.

Comment: Note that HTTPbis is going to establish a registry for authentication schemes, and the initial contents will be something like: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-authscheme-registrations-latest.html

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, yes it's a valid scheme, but, no, it's likely not supported by anything out of the box. You would have to implemented your own code to handle the authorization.